# Does not implement, wrong type for method

Tags: go, go-interface

Given the following Go code:

```
package main

type CatToy interface {
    Rattle() string
}

type Cat struct {
}

func (cat *Cat) Play(catToy CatToy) {
    println("The cat is playing!", catToy.Rattle())
}

type DogToy interface {
    Roll() string
}

type Dog struct {
}

func (dog *Dog) Play(dogToy DogToy) {
    println("The dog is playing!", dogToy.Roll())
}

type SuperToy struct {
}

func (toy *SuperToy) Rattle() string {
    return "Rattle!!!"
}

func (toy *SuperToy) Roll() string {
    return "Rolling..."
}

type Pet interface {
    Play(toy interface{})
}

func main() {
    cat := &Cat{}
    dog := &Dog{}
    superToy := &SuperToy{}

    // Working
    cat.Play(superToy)
    dog.Play(superToy)

    // Not Working
    pets := []Pet{cat, dog}
    for _, pet := range pets {
        pet.Play(superToy)
    }
}
```

I am getting these errors:

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:65:16: cannot use cat (type *Cat) as type Pet in array or slice literal:
    *Cat does not implement Pet (wrong type for Play method)
        have Play(CatToy)
        want Play(interface {})
./main.go:65:21: cannot use dog (type *Dog) as type Pet in array or slice literal:
    *Dog does not implement Pet (wrong type for Play method)
        have Play(DogToy)
        want Play(interface {})
```

The `SuperToy` implements both `CatToy` and `DogToy`. However, when I create an interface `Pet` with interface as an argument, I get an error. May I know how I'll be able to get an array/slice with a cat and dog inside? I want to iterate through this slice and call a function for each one. I also want to keep the `CatToy` and `DogToy` interfaces. I'm also ok with removing the `Pet` interface.

More info:
In the future, it's more likely that I'll add more `pets`. I don't think that I'll add more actions such as `Play`.

Thank you

Comment: Go offers no inheritance bases object orientation and trying to simulate it is doomed to fail. Don't try, you'll hurt yourself.

Comment: @Volker May I know the idiomatic way to implement this in Go?

Comment: Well, you redesign. You pack common functionality into an interface. You use normal functions.

Comment: After reading this http://spf13.com/post/is-go-object-oriented/, it seems that inheritance is the only thing that needs to be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

I get what you are trying to do, but it's impossible: your `Cat` and `Dog` types do not implement the `Pet` interface, as their `Play` methods take different types, so you won't be able to just call `Play` on them with your `SuperToy`.

To fix this, you would need to create a `Toy` interface that has both the `Roll` and the `Rattle` methods, and make `Pet.Play`, `Cat.Play` and `Dog.Play` take this interface as an argument.

```
package main

type Cat struct {
}

func (cat *Cat) Play(catToy Toy) {
    println("The cat is playing!", catToy.Rattle())
}

type Dog struct {
}

func (dog *Dog) Play(dogToy Toy) {
    println("The dog is playing!", dogToy.Roll())
}

type Toy interface {
    Roll() string
    Rattle() string
}

type SuperToy struct {
}

func (toy *SuperToy) Rattle() string {
    return "Rattle!!!"
}

func (toy *SuperToy) Roll() string {
    return "Rolling..."
}

type Pet interface {
    Play(toy Toy)
}

func main() {
    cat := &Cat{}
    dog := &Dog{}
    superToy := &SuperToy{}

    // Working
    cat.Play(superToy)
    dog.Play(superToy)

    // Not Working
    pets := []Pet{cat, dog}
    for _, pet := range pets {
        pet.Play(superToy)
    }
}
```

Gives the output

```
The cat is playing! Rattle!!!
The dog is playing! Rolling...
The cat is playing! Rattle!!!
The dog is playing! Rolling...
```

Comment: I would really like to keep the `CatToy` and `DogToy` interfaces, because I'm planning to extract `Cat` and `Dog` to separate packages/projects. Is there another alternative?

Comment: I'm afraid not, as Volker mentioned in his comment, Go does not support inheritance and what you are trying to do it clearly translating your object-oriented habits into Go code.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the Play methods to take an `interface{}` and then do a type assertion inside the method:

```
func (dog *Dog) Play(toy interface{}) {
    dogToy, isDogToy := toy.(DogToy)
    if !isDogToy {
        println("The dog does not know what to do with this toy!")
        return
    }
    println("The dog is playing!", dogToy.Roll())
}
```

Full executable example on Go Playground:

https://play.golang.org/p/LZZ-HqpzR-Z

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution! However, `type checking` is commonly a code smell so I want to avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another working solution:

```
package main

type CatToy interface {
    Rattle() string
}

type Cat struct {
    Toy CatToy
}

func (cat *Cat) Play() {
    println("The cat is playing!", cat.Toy.Rattle())
}

type DogToy interface {
    Roll() string
}

type Dog struct {
    Toy DogToy
}

func (dog *Dog) Play() {
    println("The dog is playing!", dog.Toy.Roll())
}

type SuperToy struct {
}

func (toy *SuperToy) Rattle() string {
    return "Rattle!!!"
}

func (toy *SuperToy) Roll() string {
    return "Rolling..."
}

type Pet interface {
    Play()
}

func main() {
    superToy := &SuperToy{}
    cat := &Cat{superToy}
    dog := &Dog{superToy}

    // Working
    cat.Play()
    dog.Play()

    // Working also
    pets := []Pet{cat, dog}
    for _, pet := range pets {
        pet.Play()
    }
}
```

This solution keeps the `Cat + CatToy` and `Dog + DogToy` independent from the `main + SuperToy`. This allows extraction to separate packages.

However, I do somewhat agree with @Volker and @Ullaakut. This solution seems not idiomatic for Go. I'm still not sure about the proper solution.